# Escape de caracteres en Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Tengo un String en javascript que corresponde a un xml, el cual, al asignarlo como valor de una propiedad, me escapa las comillas con `"&quot;"`, pero necesito que también  escape los signos "<" y ">", lo cual no está haciendo.

Este es un ejemplo del xml:

```
<row row="0" XMLContent="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'>"></row>
```

Decidí hacerlo con un replace:

```
value.replaceAll("<", "&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
m_row.attributes.getNamedItemNS(null, name).value = value;
```

Pero al hacer esto, lo está asignando de esta forma:

```
<row row="0" XMLContent="&amp;lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; &amp;gt;"></row>
```

El ampersand del código para escapar a "<" y ">", está siendo escapado también, haciendo que quede así:

De `"&lt;"` a `"&amp;lt;"` y lo mismo para `"&gt;"` así que cuando tomo el valor de ese atributo e intento parsear a XML, me genera un error, ya que no puede ser interpretado.

Agradecería mucho una respuesta.

Comment: ¿Estás escapando todos los caracteres con `replaceAll`? Si es así, es importante que reemplaces `&` primero, porque si no pasa lo que dices. El orden de los demás caracteres no importa, pero `&` tiene que ser el primero.